# one second order factor with two first order factors: I fix the factor loadings to be equivalent and set the variance of F3 to 1.

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I fixed the factor loadings of two first order factors (F1 and F2) to be equal and set the variance of F3 to 1. F3 is a second order factor. I did it because I read in research gate that this is the only possibility to get results from them. Now if I look into the unstandaridized factor loadings I see the same number (1,21), but when I see the standardized factor loadings I see .97 for F2 and .75 for F1. I am not sure about how to interpret it. Any help/suggestion?

Comment: If you have two first order factors, then a second order factor analysis is the same as having two correlated factors. All the second order factor is doing is accounting for that correlation in a different way, and the models are equivalent.

Comment: In short, you probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: You have fixed the unstandardized loadings to be equal, not the standardized loadings. In order for those to be the same you will need to impose additional model constraints

Comment: Would it be better a two correlated factors model, then? If so, I guess I have to fix the variance of each factor to 1 before the analysis. Right? When I do it, the get CFI = .99, TLI = .98, RMSEA = .03 (all these looks wonderfull!!!)